# Precondition check failed

Tags: java, google-classroom

it is been a while I use Google Classroom API till now it went so well, but  I want to use `setScheduledTime` method for the announcement but  didn't work I am getting the following error

```java
Classroom service = new Classroom.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
   .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
   .build();

Classroom.Courses courses2 = service.courses();
Material a = new Material();
a.setDriveFile(pptx2);
List<Material> materialNames = new ArrayList<>();
materialNames.add(a);
Announcement announcement = new Announcement().setScheduledTime("2021-11-20T23:48:00Z").setText("New Announcement").setMaterials(materialNames);
courses2.announcements().create("426056383414", announcement).execute();
```

This is the error I'm getting

```json
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
  "status" : "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To schedule an announcement for a future timestamp, you need to set it's current `state` to `DRAFT`:

```java
Announcement announcement = new Announcement()setState("DRAFT").setScheduledTime("2021-11-20T23:48:00Z").setText("New Announcement").setMaterials(materialNames);
```